# How to declare a value from commandparameter as global

Tags: c#, wpf

How can we set a CommandParameter value as global.

here is my code

```
public partial class uctrlClientDetailPage : UserControl
{
    public uctrlClientDetailPage(int ClientId)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

//Passing Value

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    Button btn = (Button)e.OriginalSource;                
    uctrlClientDetailPage objuctrlProxyDetails = new uctrlClientDetailPage(int.Parse(btn.CommandParameter.ToString()));
}
```

I pass ClientId as CommandParameter from another page.I want to declare this clientId as global
How can I set this.

thanks in advance for help...

Comment: What do you mean by global?

Comment: I am using enums and [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) (to convert from `string` given in the xaml) to pass parameters.

Comment: @peter I want to get the ClientId globally

Comment: Seems a bit messy to set it as global, bu if you want to... use a public static property on a well-suited class maybe?!